# What is a good print command to use to notify ExcelWriter has created a file?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm creating an excel workbook with many `pandas` dataframes for the sheets. It will run and create the file, but the code I found below does not give a good print command notification.

What is a good way to do that?

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1':[9,3,4,5,1,1,1,1], 'col2':[6,7,8,9,5,5,5,5]}) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1':[25,35,45,55,65,75], 'col2':[61,71,81,91,21,31]}) 

with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='testSheetJ', startrow=1, startcol=0)
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='testSheetJ', startrow=1+len(df)+3, startcol=0)
```

Comment: Just add a `print("File created")` line after it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

if os.path.exists('test.xlsx'):
    print('test.xlsx is present')
```